# Login to SQL Server from command line

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am trying to access a SQL Server 2014 database from *cmd*. I am using the literal command below where the only thing I am changing is the `servername`:

```
sqlcmd [ /E ] [ /S servername ]
```

However I get an error:

> Sqlcmd: '[': Unknown Option. Enter '-?' for help.

Any idea what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax for Connecting to a default instance by using Windows Authentication to interactively run Transact-SQL statements

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>
```

Connecting to a named instance by using Windows Authentication to interactively run Transact-SQL statements:

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName>
```

Connecting to a named instance by using Windows Authentication and specifying input and output files:

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -i <MyScript.sql> -o <MyOutput.rpt>
```

Connecting to the default instance on the local computer by using Windows Authentication, executing a query, and having sqlcmd remain running after the query has finished running:

```
sqlcmd -q "SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person"
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is `sqlcmd /E /S servername` i.e. without the square brackets.